# Adding histogram on slider in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, rad-controls

How can I draw a histogram on the Radslider like the image shown below using C# WPF? I've searched on net but not getting info.

[image]

Comment: create desired template, for reference see [Slider Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Actually you should try to ask on Teleric forums. They are nice :)

Comment: I've posted the same question on telerik forum but i've not got any reply so it would be gr8 if someone answers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

```
               <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1"  Margin="7,-72,7.5,0">
                     <telerik:RadCartesianChart Palette="Summer" >
                          <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                             <telerik:CategoricalAxis Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                         <telerik:LinearAxis Visibility="Hidden" MajorStep="20" />
                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                        <telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding KeyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" CategoryBinding="Key" ValueBinding="Value">
                            <telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplates>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Width="3" Fill="SkyBlue"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplates>
                        </telerik:BarSeries>
                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
            </StackPanel>

           <telerik:RadSlider Minimum="{Binding LowValue,Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="13" 
            Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{Binding HighValue,Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectionEnd="{Binding SelectionHigh,Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectionStart="  {Binding SelectionLow,Mode=TwoWay}"
            TickPlacement="TopLeft"  
            SelectionChanged="RadSlider_SelectionChanged" SelectionRangeEnabled="True" 
            IsDirectionReversed="False" SmallChange="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">                        
             </telerik:RadSlider>
```

Instead of customizing RadSlider you can add a RadChart & RadSlider in the same column as I've shown.
I am just putting the Xaml code With the bindings, Now you can write the logic for histogram.